# Height profile ArcGIS in wrong order

Tags: arcgis-online, elevation, arcgis-experience-builder

I am creating an experience in ArcGIS Online with GPX data. As input I am using the shapefile of the polyline of the track. When this track is represented on the elevation profile, it puts the different pieces in the wrong order as you can see. The first 2 km have to be reversed in the profile, the next 2 km also and the some other pieces.

The datasource is a "track"-file from the original GPX file, and looks like this, there are no different "parts" visible:
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: How many features are in the data source, and in what order are they in the file?

Comment: I added a screenshot. In the attribute table there is just one row containing the polyline.

Comment: It still seems to be garbage in, garbage out. How many parts in the geometry? How did you assemble the track? Can you provide Well-Known Text?